# How to key into deeply nested dictionary and list structure

Tags: python, dictionary

In the given

```
d = {'d1':[1,2,{'d2':['this is tricky',{'tough':[1,2,['me']]}]}]}
```

The questions asks me to print `'me'`.

I tried to understand the given keys and values in the dictionary to find any relationship based on the key was unable to do so.

Is there a certain function is should be aware of before diving further?

Comment: `print(dct["d1"][2]["d2"][1]["tough"][2][0])`

Comment: When you say *"The questions asks me to print 'me'."*, if this is a homework or quiz, tell us what the question says. Because I assume they don't really expect you to code a recursive descent expansion of a nested dict until you find the desired string. Is the question merely asking what syntax you use to lookup the dict? surely not something more complex?

Comment: The original version of this question used `dict` as a variable name. This is a bad idea, as it would shadow the built-in Python function `dict` (this means you cannot use `dict(...)` to create new dictionaries any more). See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20406598.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We started with:

```
d = {'d1':[1,2,{'d2':['this is tricky',{'tough':[1,2,['me']]}]}]}
```

Let's see how we can navigate through the data, one step at a time:

```
>>> d = {'d1':[1,2,{'d2':['this is tricky',{'tough':[1,2,['me']]}]}]}
>>> d['d1']
[1, 2, {'d2': ['this is tricky', {'tough': [1, 2, ['me']]}]}]
>>> d['d1'][2]
{'d2': ['this is tricky', {'tough': [1, 2, ['me']]}]}
>>> d['d1'][2]['d2']
['this is tricky', {'tough': [1, 2, ['me']]}]
>>> d['d1'][2]['d2'][1]
{'tough': [1, 2, ['me']]}
>>> d['d1'][2]['d2'][1]['tough']
[1, 2, ['me']]
>>> d['d1'][2]['d2'][1]['tough'][2]
['me']
>>> d['d1'][2]['d2'][1]['tough'][2][0]
'me'
```

At the end, we have the desired code for the original problem: `d['d1'][2]['d2'][1]['tough'][2][0]`.

Comment: Please do NOT post images of code. Please copy and paste the text instead. Text is more accessible to everybody (be it screen readers, the google bot or people why simply want to copy part of the code)

Answer (score 6):

Break it down into steps. You started with:

```
d = {'d1':[1,2,{'d2':['this is tricky',{'tough':[1,2,['me']]}]}]}
```

```
me = 'me'
tough = [1, 2, [me]]
d2 = ['this is tricky', {'tough': tough}]
d1 = [1, 2, {'d2': d2}]
d = {'d1': d1}
```

To access me from `me` from `tough`

```
print(tough[2][0])
```

To access me from `tough` from `d2`

```
print(d2[1]['tough'])
```

To access me from `d2` from `d1`

```
print(d1[2]['d2'])
```

To access me from `d1` from `dict`

```
print(d['d1'])
```

Chaining them all together

```
d['d1'][2]['d2'][1]['tough'][2][0]
```